# StringReplace x Array

Tags: delphi

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 Nomes: array[1..10] of string=('Tadeu','Joao','Maria','Ana','Juca','leticia');
 StringReplace(Edit1.Text, Nomes, 'Bloqueado', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Preciso fazer com que o StringReplace procure qualquer nome que esteja dentro do array e substitua. Aonde estou errando ?

Comment: Ok obrigado @TiagoSilva pela dica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo o que consegui entender do que você apresentou, precisa mudar no vetor o nome digitado no ***edit*** pelo valor `'Bloqueado'`.

Vai ter que fazer registro por registro do vetor.

```
var
  I: integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Nomes) to High(Nomes) do
    Nomes[I] := StringReplace(Nomes[I], Edit1.Text, 'Bloqueado', [rfReplaceAll]);
...
end;
```